# Reading Specific rows of an excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to read the excel sheet from 2nd row to some 13th row and also want to get the corresponding column values.please provide me the code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and ask about the problem you've faced.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? This isn't a free coding service.

Comment: i have get the row index's of rows what i want and iterate the in for loop.but its not working fine

Comment: i know this is not free coding service.if u want to help u can no need to discourage.@http://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/bmorris591

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [reading the documentation that comes with Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)!

Taken straight from there:

```
// Decide which rows to process
int rowStart = Math.min(1, sheet.getFirstRowNum()); // 0 based not 1 based rows
int rowEnd = Math.max(12, sheet.getLastRowNum());

for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
   Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

   int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);

   for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
      Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      if (c == null) {
         // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
      } else {
         // Do something useful with the cell's contents
      }
   }
}
```

[This bit of the docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) covers how to get the value of a cell

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ApachePoiDoc
{
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, URISyntaxException
  {
    URL url = new URL( "http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook" );
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse( url.toURI() );
  }
}
```